# How can I create sub packages?

Tags: netbeans, java-ee-6

Below is my project list in Netbeans.  Whenever I try to create a new package under `contentmanagement` it won't actually add it as a child, it adds it as a sibling.  Is it not possible to create subpackages?

[image: My project list in Netbeans]

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at the name of the newly created package. Is it `contentmanagement.newpackage` by any chance? I recently updated to 7.0 and noticed subpackages are no longer rendered as children in the Projects window, but the package declaration in the source file is correct.

Comment: Ok, glad to know it used to be nested.  The package name is correct but it's not showing as a child.  Have you found a way to get it to show as a child?  Do we know if this is a bug in Netbeans?

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or a feature. I just accepted that is the way things are going to be :)

Comment: @Webnet It's never too late to answer a question :) This is not a bug. Right click on empty space in Projects window to open a context menu and then select "View java packages as" → "Reduced tree" (or "Tree" if needed). Tested in Netbeans 8.0.1.

Comment: @VIK, I did not realise this for the two years for which I've been using Netbeans. A massive thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this same issue, and the annoying thing is that when you go to import from those "subpackages" you cannot find them under the parent package.

say you wanted childPack which you thought you put inside parentPack.
you can't get it by:

```
import parentPack.*;
```

rather it has to be

```
import parentPack.childPack; /// it appears that's just 
// the package name, not its location in parent pack
```